# codeigniter not recall correctly controller function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have created a simple web page with a button, on click of this button I want to change that part of the page by loading a page in the present invoices. The code I wrote is as follows:

Index with button:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

        <title>Justified Nav Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>



        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /*
                 * ACCETTAZIONE
                 */
                $("#ricoveraPaziente").click(function() {
                    alert("adassdaasdasdsd");
                    $('#quiiiiii').load('fatture/index');
                    //e.preventDefault();


                });


            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="masthead">
                <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="ricoveraPaziente">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="quiiiiii">

                <!-- Jumbotron -->
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Marketing stuff!</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>
                </div>

                <!-- Example row of columns -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
                        <p class="text-danger">As of v7.0.1, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Site footer -->
                <div class="footer">
                    <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- /container -->

        </div>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The controller that call in the fragment JQuery is:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Fatture extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('fatture');
    }
}
```

When I click on the button codeigniter does not make me appear any page, how can I fix it? please: D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#ricoveraPaziente").click(function() {
    alert("adassdaasdasdsd");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fatture/index',
        success: function(result){
            $('#quiiiiii').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tried your code, but unfortunately noin still works. I do not understand why, I've done other projects with codeigniter and everyone has always worked. Now I can not get it to go well. I'm desperate.

Comment: check what error (or notification) do you get in the console !?

Comment: http://lord112.altervista.org/112112112.png -> Chrome Console Report. help Me Please :(

Comment: The problem is solved by adding index.php / ControllerName, in this way the ajax calls work perfectly

Comment: yes you could always use the full path to prevent any inconviniancies.
`url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/fatture/index';`